# Is there something similar to execlp() that doesn't replace your current process?

Tags: c++, exec

I am looking for something that works similar to `unistd.h`'s `execlp()`, but spawns a new child process instead of replacing your current one. Does something like this exist?

I use Arch Linux, in case it matters.

**Example:**

```cpp
// temp.cpp    

#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  
    std::cout << "This line prints just fine!\n";

    execlp("gcc", "gcc", "test.c", (const char*)NULL);

    std::cout << "This one doesn't...\n";
}
```

```
$ touch test.c
$ g++ temp.cpp -o temp
$ ./temp
This line prints just fine!
$
```

Comment: The usual method is to call `fork` and then one of the `exec` functions in the child.

Comment: `if (fork() == 0) execlp("gcc", "gcc", "test.c", (const char*)NULL);`

Comment: execlp does not "destroy" the current process.  It causes the current process to be transformed; from a caterpillar into a butterfly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking for [posix_spawn()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/posix_spawn.html), which does pretty much what you describe. Some platforms implement it in terms of `fork()` and `exec()` but others don't waste time duplicating all the page tables and memory space only to overwrite them, which is especially a problem on systems with no overcommit or swap.

There's also the [system()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/system.html) call if you don't mind spawning a subshell to run your child. That can be heavyweight.

Comment: I never really like using `system()` as it can be a big security hole.